# Error in gpd.join related to 'PyGEOSSTRTreeIndex'

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, rtree

I have an error related to `gpd.sjoin` which shows as follows

```
NameError: name 'PyGEOSSTRTreeIndex' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
alltitresQuartiers = gpd.sjoin(left_df=transactions_located, right_df=quartiers,  how="left", predicate="intersects")
```

This join worked well in other scripts I wrote in the past but not this time.

I have already installed `rtree`, `pygeos` and `geopandas` but no success in `gpd.join`.

I have tried to set `gpd.options.use_pygeos = True` but no success either. I wonder what went wrong?

Both geodataframes have geometries.

When I uninstalled pygeos  I got the following error:

```
 NameError: name 'pygeos' is not defined
```

However when I install it i get the error i mentioned above.

Any help is welcome

Comment: The key dependencies of `geopandas` have been changing over recent versions (0.13, 0.14, future 1.0) - see https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/pygeos_to_shapely.html for more info. Going forward the recommendation is to drop `pygeos` and use `shapely>=2`. The `rtree` package should be optional too, as shapely >=2 has an STRTree implementation https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/strtree.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem.

(1) I added this module on the top of the script

```
# Geospatial libraries

import geopandas as gpd
import pygeos
gpd.options.use_pygeos = True
```

(2) I restarted the kernel

`gdp.join` worked fine after that.